# While loop wont print twice

Tags: javascript, html, web

Currently I'm trying to print two copies of the same receipt without using the browser-print dialogue. Now unfortunately there is no way to pass the number of copies to the print dialog so the only solution I came up with is doing it in a LOOP, but when looping the print command it does not work! while looping the whole POST method works just fine.

Here's the code before I enter the loop
print function

```
function p_print(receipt) {

        $('#receipt_section').html(receipt.html_content);
        __currency_convert_recursively($('#receipt_section'));
        __print_receipt('receipt_section');
    
}
```

Code without Loop

```
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                if (result.success == 1) {
                    if (result.mail_enabled) {
                        window.open(result.mail_enabled);
                    }
                    $('#modal_payment').modal('hide');
                    toastr.success(result.msg);


                    //Check if enabled or not
                    if (result.receipt.is_enabled) {
                        p_print(result.receipt);
                    }
                } else {
                    toastr.error(result.msg);
                }
            },
        });
```

Functioning loop that prints twice but also POSTS the data twice

```
        var Count = 0;
        var Copies = 2; 
        while ( Count < Copies ) {
        $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: data,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                if (result.success == 1) {
                    if (result.mail_enabled) {
                        window.open(result.mail_enabled);
                    }
                    $('#modal_pay').modal('hide');
                    toastr.success(result.msg);


                    if (result.receipt.is_enabled) {
                        p_print(result.receipt);
                    }
                } else {
                    toastr.error(result.msg);
                }
            },
        });
        Count ++;  
        };
```

Now If I apply the loop only on `p_print(result.receipt)` it wont print twice, only by applying it to the whole POST request it would then print twice but also stores the data twice which is not a proper solution at all.

Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just call p_print twice in the if clause?  I mean, you could put the while loop there, but it seems like overkill, when you could just duplicate the line.

Comment: Is this a PHP problem, or a Javascript problem? Why is this tagged with PHP, but does not contain any such code?

Comment: Is `__print_receipt` an asynchronous function? Can you provide its definition?

Comment: Do you really need to force two copies to be printed, you can’t shift that burden to the user to decide?

Comment: @ChrisStrickland I did call it twice but it wont print twice which is very weird so far

Comment: @NicoHaase My bad, very sorry about that.

Comment: function __print_receipt(section_id = null) {

        setTimeout(function() {
            window.print();

            // setTimeout(function() {
            //     $('#receipt_section').html('');
            // }, 5000);
            
        }, 1000);
    }

Comment: @ChrisHaas it's a button specially made to print two copies of a receipt: one for the store and the other for the customer

Comment: I see. Then I think you just need to duplicate the HTML and force a page break with CSS.